# zenity list in forms dialog is not viewable

Tags: gtk, programming, zenity

What I am trying to do is this:

```
zenity --forms --add-list my_list --list-values="one|two|three"
```

What I get is this:

[image]

That white line in the center is the list , which for some reason has no width whatsoever. How do I configure that ?

I am not certain whether this is a bug or something users have to configure themselves. Zenity's `--help-forms` and man page don't shed any light on this whatsoever

**NOTE**: I know about `zenity --list` option, but I need to make it works specifically with `--forms`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Zenity. I have not found a way to directly fix this, but a "workaround".

If you add another kind of forms widget, like `--add-entry`, which correctly expands to the full dialog window width, the list widget will expand to full width too.

Example:

```
zenity --forms --add-list="interfaces" --list-values="eth0|eth1|wlan0" --add-entry="foo"
```

[image: zenity dialog image]

You should pick a widget which is useful for your dialog though, simply throwing a "foo" entry at the bottom of your dialogue which has no meaning is not what they call user friendliness. ;-)